# Boot issue after format an old partition

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, mount

I use UbuntuStudio 18.04.1 LTS.

Inside the main HDD, I had an NTFS partition with some problems I couldn't fix from inside Ubuntu, so... I decided to full format that partition.

Well, the issue is that I had to forget something in the process because now I can not to start the system (the starting process tells me about an error related with the UUID of that partition).

I had tried to fix this with the "Recovery Mode" but... From some reason I don't know, it doesn't work so fine (I can not to access any options and I have to reset the PC to start over again).

Also I had tried to fix this with the Ubuntu Live CD, but... When I try to edit the "**/etc/fstab**" and/or "**/boot/grub/grub.cfg**" files... I can not to find those main system files!

The "**fstab**" I get with the Live CD is just a 59 bytes file with this text inside:

> overlay / overlay rw 0 0
>
> tmpfs /tmp tmpfs nosuid,nodev 0 0

There is no any "**grub.cfg**" showed by the Live CD.

So... How can I fix this?

I know what I have to do (edit the mentioned file with the right UUID number), but... How can I do it?

Comment: When using the 'live' cd, are you mounting your hdd & navigating to the /mount-dir/etc/fstab file to look at your file-system-table & not just looking at /etc/fstab which applies to your live-cd environment?

Comment: I'm not sure about your question because I'm not a Linux expert user, But... I guess, just guess, that Live-CD is mounting in a way I can not to see the original UbuntuStudio filesystem at all. I mean, with the Live-CD File Manager, I just can see a File System which is not my original HDD file system. Whatever, Is there some way to manually change the UUID of the partition (because I have the old number, but I don't know if I can change it).

Comment: When in the live environment, post the output to `parted --list`, then leave a comment @Fabby

Comment: The file-system you see in a 'live' environment is a fs created on boot in memory; why you can use the 'live' system without doing damage to whatever OS is on the machine already  (I won't use other peoples windows systems, but will use their hardware with my 'live' thumb-drive).  You need to `mount` your hdd systems in order to use (view or change) anything on them.   follow Fabby's suggestion

Comment: I don't know if the following is "THE" official way to fix this, but... I used the Live-CD session (Try Ubuntu not Install it) to get the right UUID number with Gparted, I wrote it into a paper and... I restart my system in a normal way. When the error happened, the system stops and go to the "Emergency Status". This is, basically, a Terminal line command session. I used the old "sudo nano /etc/fstab" to edit that file changing the UUID number of the problematic device, saved it and I restarted the system. Believe it or not... I "SAVED" THE WHOLE SYSTEM! Now all is working so fine!

Comment: But... I wonder... Why Linux doesn't perform this job automatically each time we're partitioning and/or formatting a unit? Why the user have to do this? Just a question.